# pandas: how to format cells after exporting to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am exporting some pandas dataframes to Excel:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet)
wb = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets[sheet]
ws.write(1, 4, "DataFrame contains ...")
writer.save()
```

I understand I can use the format class: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/format.html to format cells as I write them to Excel. However, I can't figure out a way to apply a formatting style *after* cells have already been written to Excel. E.g. how do I set to bold and horizontally align to the centre the item in row = 2 and column = 3 of the dataframne I have exported to Excel?

Comment: Why don't you use the formatting before writing to Excel?

Comment: Because I need to format only certain rows and only certain columns of the dataframe which is output to Excel in one go with df.to_excel(writer,sheet) as above

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
new_style = wb.add_format().set_bold().set_align('center')
ws.apply_style(sheet, 'C2', new_style)
```

According to `apply_style()` that need to be added to XLSXwriter:

```
def apply_style(self, sheet_name, cell, cell_format_dict):
        """Apply style for any cell, with value or not. Overwrites cell with joined 
        cell_format_dict and existing format and with existing or blank value"""

        written_cell_data = self.written_cells[sheet_name].get(cell)
        if written_cell_data:
            existing_value, existing_cell_format_dict = self.written_cells[sheet_name][cell]
            updated_format = dict(existing_cell_format_dict or {}, **cell_format_dict)
        else:
            existing_value = None
            updated_format = cell_format_dict

        self.write_cell(sheet_name, cell, existing_value, updated_format)
```

OR you can write so:

```
new_style = wb.add_format().set_bold().set_align('center')
ws.write(2, 3, ws.written_cells[sheet].get('C2), new_style)
```

Comment: I'm confused: do you mean you have modified the classes of XLSxwriter so as to add apply_style() ? I couldn't find apply_style documented anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you need to add this func to your XLSXwriter.

Comment: Is it possible to set_bg_color a range of cells rather than whole column?