# Split Excel file into multiple files using Python

Tags: python, excel, split, openpyxl

I have an Excel spreadsheet with almost 40,000 rows of entries. I would like to split this Excel file into multiple files based upon the values in Column C starting with Row 6. I've been able to determine how to split the file, but the challenge I seem to be having is getting the header rows to carry over. This is a specific template for the ArchivesSpace Application and for whatever reason the information in Rows 1-5 must be present. I've tried deleting this information and using only the field codes and that was not successful. Here is the code I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('container_list_master.xlsx')
column_name = 'ead'
unique_values = df[column_name].unique()

for unique_value in unique_values:
    df_output = df[df[column_name].str.contains(unique_value)]
    output_path =os.path.join('output', unique_value + '.xlsx')
    df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value, index=False)
```

[image: Here is an image of the Excel Spreadsheet]

Comment: I'd suggest working directly with openpyxl in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

With some minor alterations, your code can be adapted to produce your desired output.

The couple main points you were missing to have it all:

- `df = pd.read_excel('container_list_master.xlsx', skiprows=range(4))`
  This line has the `skiprows` parameter which does exactly what it sounds like and allows you to skip the first few non-table lines while reading in the file.
- `df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value, startrow=4, index=False)` Same concept for `startrow` as `skiprows`, except for writing.
- Creating a writer object, then using that writer object to put in some of your header cells [as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469018), which is demonstrated below.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
# import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('container_list_master.xlsx', skiprows=range(4))
column_name = 'EAD ID'
unique_values = df[column_name].unique()

for unique_value in unique_values:
    df_output = df[df[column_name].str.contains(unique_value)]
    output_path = os.path.join('output', unique_value + '.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_path)
    df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=unique_value, startrow=4, index=False)
    
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(1, 1, 'This is the template for importing ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(2, 1, 'Mapping - ArchivesSpace ... SECTION')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(3, 1, 'Mapping - ArchivesSpace ... FIELD')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 1, 'ArchivesSpace field code ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(2, 2, 'Resource ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(3, 2, 'The resource ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 2, 'Collection id ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(2, 3, 'Resource ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(3, 3, 'EAD ID ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 3, 'ead ...')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 4, 'res_uri')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 5, 'ref_id')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 6, 'title')
    writer.sheets[unique_value].cell(4, 7, 'something unique')
    writer.close()
```

Here is the input I used, which is a vague rendition of your screen cap:
[image: demo input]

And here is the output it generated:
[image: demo output file]

The output looks a little tacky, but if this is just an import for a software then who cares? If the answer is you, then here is a link with information about how to format it as well: [xlsx writer documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) or from [another excellent answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34858346).

Let me know if you have any questions!